# XCode 12.2 color literal from assets

Tags: ios, swift, assets, xcode12

Before if we drag assets colorliteral we can see the color with rgb but now if we drag color from assets it shows syntax like "color("filename"), how can i get old xcode like result in xcode 12.2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gsUK.jpg

Comment: I have no clue what you wants exactly. Please, clarify your problem and question!

Comment: Have you checked the image?

Comment: I have the same issue after updating to Xcode 12.2.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal but you can use `UIColor(named: "CaseTypePrivate")`

I can't seem to find any way to get the `#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)` that we used to get when you drag-and-dropped from the assets menu.

One bonus at least of the first answer is that it will reflect any changes you make to your color assets; whereas the `colorLiteral` approach effectively hard-codes the color value.

Comment: Yes uicolor and #colorLiteral we can edit by ouselves, but that previous approach was very fast.

Comment: The problem is that a color set is now a dynamic collection of multiple colors, so a literal giving rgb values makes no sense and that feature was removed.